# Why does WriteLine in C# change my format in Text File?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

So I'm writing an app and without any problem I was getting streamwriter to write new lines using the WriteLine. However, when I got to a certain textbox it automatically started indenting. Please see below image and code:

This is under a save button

```
        SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
        sfd.InitialDirectory = @"C:\DR\Desktop\4-22-18";
        sfd.RestoreDirectory = true;
        sfd.FileName = "G-12";
        sfd.Filter = "txt files(*.txt)|*.txt| Word Files | *.doc";

        if (sfd.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Stream fileStream = sfd.OpenFile();
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileStream);
            sw.WriteLine(lblDate.Text);
            sw.WriteLine(lblTime.Text);
            sw.WriteLine("\r");
            sw.WriteLine("G-12"+"\t"+ lblNotes.Text + " " + txtNotes.Text);
            sw.WriteLine("==========================================");
            sw.WriteLine(lblSG.Text+" "+ nmSG.Text);
            sw.WriteLine("==========================================");
            sw.WriteLine(lblTinWeight.Text + "  " + nmTinWeight.Text);
            sw.WriteLine(lblKIO3.Text + " "+ nmKIO3Volume.Text);
            sw.WriteLine(lblKIO3N.Text + nmKIO3N.Text);
            sw.WriteLine(lblTinPercentage.Text + " "+ lblTinPercent.Text);
            sw.WriteLine(lblTinGram.Text + lblTinGrams.Text);
            sw.WriteLine("==========================================");
            sw.WriteLine(lblNeutWeight.Text+nmNeutWeight.Text);
            sw.WriteLine(lblNeutVolume.Text+nmNaOHVolume.Text);
            sw.WriteLine(lblNeutNormality.Text + nmNaOHNormality.Text);
            sw.Close();
        }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLlNq.png)

Comment: I see no indentation.  Are you talking about the `34.25`?

Comment: Yes, that and the 5.96, they are pushed down below instead of to the side...

Comment: Hard to tell that is the problem since there is nothing in the post describing the desired output.  Thats what `WriteLine` does - if you put the `lblTinGram` and ` lblTinGrams` in a different `WritelIne` it will go on the next line.  `WriteLine` has gobs of overrides that you can specify a format

Comment: I just added .Trim() to the end of the textboxes as follows:

lblKIO3N.Text.Trim() and this fixed the issue.

Comment: Bear in mind that using `+` is 'slow'.  Use either `$"{thing}{otherthing}"` or `WriteLine("{0}{1}", thing, otherthing);`.  Stop using `+` before it becomes a habit.

Comment: Look at the value of `lblTinPercentage.Text` in the debugger.

Comment: Writing "\r" to a text file is not a good idea, text editors can get pretty confuzzled about that.  Very odd choice, if you also did that when setting those labels' Text property then you do get that output.

Answer (score 1):

The text box contains a space. Verify this by looking the value of `lblTinWeight.Text` (or a different textbox, not sure) in the debugger.